# Sync Error 80004005 while trying to sync podcasts

Tags: 8.0, sync, music, podcast, synchronization

If I try to sync some podcast to my Windows Phone 8 (Nokia Lumia 920), I get the error 80004005 in the Windows Phone Desktop App after the sync - here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

The mentioned files are also on the phone download queue.

[image: download queue]
[image: download queue]

I found this [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpmusic/8x-music-sync-error-code-80004005/5f00a8fb-249d-4e0b-87b0-9b4ddf19f012) in MSFT Windows Phone community, and checked if my podcast has some trailing spaces. But the tags are fine and without any trailing space.

Any advice or hint is very appreciated.

Comment: Got same error. Turned off/on my phone and it was solved.